# How can be saved login detail in Native Script

Tags: nativescript

When I sign in, my login should be saved, I don't want to enter the userName Password each and every login time.

below my code :

```
login() {
        this.userService.login(this.user)
            .subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
            },
            (error) => alert(error)
            );
    }
```

userService.ts

```
 return this.http.post(
      url,
      JSON.stringify({
        name: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }),
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
        responseType: 'text'
      }
    )
      .map((response: any) => {
        for (var x in response) {
          if (response.hasOwnProperty(x)) {

          }
        }
        console.log("_body: " + response._body);
        return response._body;
      })
      .catch(this.handleErrors)
  }
```

Comment: React-native and NativeScript are two different frameworks so the tags are kind of confusing (removing the react tag but feel free to correct me if you are using this framework and not NativeScript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NativeScript has exposed the [application-settings module](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application-settings). The Application Settings module is used to store strings, booleans, and numbers in a built-in key/value store. Uses `SharedPreferences` on Android and `NSUserDefaults` on iOS.

So for example, you could store the login information and use it to check if the user has already been logged in (just as you would do in native Android & iOS projects) - [demo POC here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/services/login.service.ts#L34-L35)

Comment: It's good to note that these preferences are simply saved on a file on the disk, and thus meant for just that: preferences and defaults. My answer below expands on this and shows an alternative that uses encrypted storage on the device, meant for privacy sensitive data like email addresses and passwords :)

Answer (score 4):

It's good to keep in mind that any keys and values written to the `UserDefaults` and `SharedPreferences`, so the native APIs that are used by the application settings module and the `getString` and `setString` methods are simply stored on the disk, for anyone with access to the phone to see. This API is not meant for storing sensitive data, and is meant solely for persisting user settings, so 'defaults' and 'preferences'.

If you want a way to securely store email addresses and passwords on the device, take a look at this library: [Nativescript-secure-storage](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-secure-storage). It does a very similar job to the aforementioned APIs but everything is encrypted so people can't just read the contents from the disk.

Comment: Surely one can use an encrypt method before storing any data to 'defaults' and 'preferences'. When retrieving it use a method to decrypt. that way only the application's code will have visibility to the data.

Answer (score 1):

Just like [@Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4936697/nick-iliev) suggested, you can use [application-settings](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application-settings%20%22application-settings) module to store your access token that you can use for underground check later when the user returns.

After successful initial login attempt, get your JWT token from the login process ( or whatever authentication mode you chosse ) and to store it for re-authentication later or just check if the key/[value] is set previously and can be used for simple offline login as well.

Answer (score 0):

use JWT, also you can use offline data. 
look at this link for example:
https://medium.com/@njwest/building-a-react-native-jwt-client-api-requests-and-asyncstorage-d1a20ab60cf4

Answer (score -2):

you can use local storage.

You may have

```
<TextField hint="{{ 'user_name' | L }}" autocorrect="false" required autocapitalizationType="none" [(ngModel)]="model.email"
                #emailModel="ngModel" name="email" keyboardType="email"></TextField>
```

While logging in the component, save it in localstorage

```
localStorage.setString("username", this.model.email);
```

in ngOnInit(), you can fetch it back

```
localStorage.getString("username");
```